# How to show two items side by side in Android PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I have two fields that I need to show side by side as shown in the image below in Android PreferenceScreen. How do I go about this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be to create a class (for example `CustomPreference`) that extends `Preference`. Within this class you can set your own xml file as layout like this:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    super.onCreateView(parent);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_id, parent, false);
    return view;
}
```

Then you can implement methods like the following to add content:

```
public void setFromSummary(String fromSummary) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
    textView.setText(fromSummary);
}
```

Comment: So that custom layout XML can have items such as `TextView`s?

Comment: Yes - you can create a normal layout and inflate it to the preference. The layout can contain anything you want - you jsut need to write a setter for every property you want to set later